# Generate a Dictionary using two lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists like so:

```
listA = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
listB = [g, h, i, j, k, l]
```

I have the following function

```
def genOneDic(dic1, dic2):
```

I would like to do something like return a joined single dic something like

```
dict(( e, dic1.get(e)) for e in listA) + dict(( e, dic2.get(e)) for e in listB)
```

That seems wrong, what's the right way to do that?

Example with dic1

```
dic1 = {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':'4', 'e':'5', 'f':'6', 'x':'10', 'z':'11'}
listA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
dict(( e, dic1.get(e)) for e in listA)
```

should return get only the fields in listA. Now when joining both listA and listB have a 'g', but they should be different in the single dic. There should be two 'g's. Would the best solution be to just prepend dic1 or dic2 to the keys and the join the dic?

Comment: Is the desired result: `{a:g, b:h, c:i,...}`?

Comment: Can you show us the dict you want created?

Comment: are you looking for `dic1.update(dic2)`?

Comment: I only need some fields from both dic1 and dic2 (only those in the list), not all of them.

Comment: Do `dic1` and `dic2` keys overlap? Looks like you just need to combine `dict.update()` as @mhlester said with dict comprehensions you have in your question.

Comment: They keys overlap but they should not override like in an update, i think adding something like `dic1.e` is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would create a dict that skips overlapped keys in two lists.

Use the [set intersection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) to find the keys in both lists:

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
listB = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

di={k:v for v,k in enumerate(listA,1) if k not in set(listA) & set(listB)}
i=max(di.values())
di.update({k:v for v,k in enumerate(listB,i) if k not in set(listA) & set(listB)})
i=max(di.values())

print di
# {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6, 'i': 8, 'h': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 9, 'l': 11}
```

Then reuse the set intersection to create the two keys for the overlapping keys. In this step, you might loose order of some of the keys in the overlap since sets are unordered:

```
for e in set(listA) & set(listB):
    di['listA.'+e]=max(di.values())+1
    di['listB.'+e]=max(di.values())+1

print di
# {'a': 1, 'listB.g': 13, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'f': 6, 'i': 8, 'h': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 9, 'l': 11, 'listA.g': 12}
```

You can use the same technique to interleave two list and dicts:

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
listB = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
dic1 = {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':'4', 'e':'5', 'f':'6', 'g':'10', 'z':'11'}
dic2 = {'g':'55', 'h':'56', 'i':'56', 'j':'57', 'k':'58', 'l':'59', 'x':'10', 'z':'11'}

di={k:dic1.get(k, None) for k in listA if k not in set(listA) & set(listB)}
di.update({k:dic2.get(k, None) for k in listB if k in set(listB)-set(listA) and k not in set(listA) & set(listB)})

for e in set(listA) & set(listB):
    di['dic1.'+e]=dic1.get(e, None)
    di['dic2.'+e]=dic2.get(e, None)

print di
# {'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'b': '2', 'e': '5', 'd': '4', 
   'f': '6', 'i': '56', 'h': '56', 'k': '58', 'j': '57', 
   'l': '59', 'dic1.g': '10', 'dic2.g': '55'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague, but I think this is what you are looking for.

```
first = {k: dic1.get(k) for k in listA }
second = {k: dic2.get(k) for k in listB } 
first.update(second)
```